# How to use NotifyOfPropertyChange in static property (Caliburn Micro)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

1. Why I can't use NotifyOfPropertyChange in a static property?
2. Is there another NotifyOfPropertyChange function in caliburn micro that can be use in static property or another way to use it and how?

   ```
   private static string _data = "";

   public static string _Data
   {
       get
       {
           return _data;
       }
       set
       {
           _data = value;
           NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => _Data);          
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own method that raises the `StaticPropertyChanged` event:

```
private static string _data = "";
public static string _Data
{
    get
    {
        return _data;
    }
    set
    {
        _data = value;
        NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(nameof(_Data));
    }
}



public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;
private static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (StaticPropertyChanged != null)
        StaticPropertyChanged(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Please refer to the following blog post for more information: http://10rem.net/blog/2011/11/29/wpf-45-binding-and-change-notification-for-static-properties

Comment: `nameof(_Data)` should be in string type like this `NotifyStaticPropertyChanged("_Data");` :) Thanks for the help :D

Comment: The nameof operator was introduced in C#6: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof

Comment: this enlighten me a lot :D i should properly use `nameof` instead of strings :)

Answer (score 0):

> Why I can't use NotifyOfPropertyChange in a static property?

Well, you can't use it as it is now because `NotifyOfPropertyChange` is an *instance* method, not a static one.

> Is there another NotifyOfPropertyChange function in caliburn micro [...]?

No, as far as I know, it isn't. However, you could roll your own implementation e.g.

```
public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private static void NotifyPropertyChange<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property)
{
    string propertyName = (((MemberExpression) property.Body).Member as PropertyInfo).Name;
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

which can then be called like this

```
NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => _Data);
```

in your property setter.

---

EDIT regarding the signature:

Instead of

```
private static void NotifyPropertyChange<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property) { ... }
```

you can just as well use

```
private static void NotifyPropertyChange([CallerMemberName] string property) { ... }
```

which has the advantage that you don't have to explicitly pass anything, you can call it just like this

```
NotifyPropertyChange();
```

because the compiler will automatically [*inject*](https://grenangen.se/node/75) the property name.

I just went for `Expression<Func<T>>` because the call is (almost) exactly the same as the call to caliburn micro's `NotifyPropertyChange`.

---

<sub>What you need to know though is that due to the `NotifyPropertyChange` method being a static instead of an instance method you *cannot* refactor it into a base class (e.g. `MyViewModelBase`) like you could do with an instance method - this is what caliburn micro does as well.</sub>

<sub>Therefore you need to copy & paste the event and the `NotifyPropertyChange<T>` method in every ViewModel that has static properties or create a static helper which wraps the functionality away.</sub>

Comment: Great! Helps a lot :) Thanks

Comment: @FrancisCanoza good to hear that it helped. Please also see the edit I have made regarding the signature of the `NotifyPropertyChange` method. You can use any signature you want to use.